# How to use a dictionary and isin()?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dictionary and I want to use that dictionary to classify a new column in a df. The `Value` column in the df should be compared to the values in the dictionary. The new column in the df should be the Key associated with the value.

```
d = {'Car':['1','2','3'],
     'Chicken legs':['4','5','6'],
     'Coronary artery bypass graft surgery':['7','8','9','10','11','12']}
```

df

```
Color   Style      Value
red     round      1
blue    square     5
green   triangle   9
orange  sphere     12
```

final df

```
Color   Style      Value   Thing
red     round      1       Car
blue    square     5       Chicken legs
green   triangle   9       Coronary artery bypass graft surgery
orange  sphere     12      Coronary artery bypass graft surgery
```

My first inclination was to put this into a df (df_dict) but I'm having trouble comparing the single value in the df to the list in the df_dict.

```
df_dict = pd.DataFrame({'Thing':list(d.keys()), 'Values':list(d.values())})

    Thing                                   Values
0   Car                                     [1, 2, 3]
1   Chicken_legs                            [4, 5, 6]
2   Coronary artery bypass graft surgery    [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

The below code works for a single element. My dictionary however has 32 elements and I imagine there is a better approach than just creating 32 versions of the code below. I just don't know what that approach would be.

```
df.loc[df['Value'].isin(['1', '2', '3]),'Thing']='Car'
```

Is it possible to use a dictionary and `isin()`?
Should I instead convert the dictionary to a list?

Comment: I will leave a hint for now because I'm short in time but you should actually reverse the dict in a way that it will turn into a lookup table like this
d = {'1':'Car', '2':'Car', ... , '6':'Chicken legs' ... }
This way you can bypass the use for isin()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a helper function for this:

```
In [60]: def argcontains(item):
    ...:     for i, v in d.items():
    ...:         if item in v:
    ...:             return i
    ...:
```

then `map` it to the appropriate column:

```
In [61]: df['thing'] = df.Value.map(argcontains)

In [62]: df
Out[62]: 
   Value                                 thing
0      1                                   Car
1      5                          Chicken legs
2      9  Coronary artery bypass graft surgery
3     12  Coronary artery bypass graft surgery
```

This can be slightly more general (and avoid recalculating `d.items()` each time, though that's pretty minor) such as:

```
In [73]: def argcontains2(item_iterator, item):
    ...:     for i, v in item_iterator:
    ...:         if item in v:
    ...:             return i
    ...:         

In [74]: from functools import partial

In [75]: argcontains = partial(argcontains2, d.items())
```

If you will need to reference the data in `d` by value often, then it will be better to create a reverse index of the data (the reverse dictionary) as mentioned in another answer.

But if you only need the reverse lookup one time for purposes of constructing this column, it will use less memory and require less computation to use a simple loop like shown above.

Comment: I only need to run this one time, so this will be the better option.

Answer (score 2):

Even better, reverse the dictionary, so you have something like:

```
v_map = {
    1: 'Car', 2: 'Car', 3: 'Car', 
    4: 'Chicken legs', 5: 'Chicken legs', 6: 'Chicken legs', 
    7: 'Coronary artery bypass graft surgery',
    ...
    12: 'Coronary artery bypass graft surgery'
}
```

Now your new column is simply a matter of plugging in `v_map[df['Value']]` for the strings in the new column.

Comment: Just a side note: this can sometimes be intractable (not saying it is the case for OP though). I previously worked on a large text ingestion system where we needed to do some reverse lookups to filter subsets of the data, and memory limitations made it impossible to simply also store a copy of the reverse mapping. I only point this out because reversing a `dict` is almost always the first thing suggested for these problems in Python, while for cases when you only need to iterate the data once to get the key from some values, it can be much better to just use a repeated boring loop.